# "Waiting for any device" when attempting to fastboot Galaxy S8

Tags: android, adb, root, samsung-galaxy, fastboot

I've been trying to install TWRP custom recovery on my galaxy s8 and haven't had much luck getting past this particular issue. After looking on several forums and watching pretty much all of the solutions on youtube I've resorted to posting my problem.

So, after enabling usb debugging and OEM unlocking I open up platform-tools in cmd prompt and type in the following:

`adb devices` - this is showing me that my device has been detected by my pc

`adb reboot bootloader` - this then takes me to the bootloader mode

`fastboot flash recovery recovery.img` - which presents me with "waiting for any device"

All the solutions that I've seen have something to do with the drivers but I believe mine is up to date after installing it manually from `C:\Users\"My Name"\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\extras\google\usb_driver`

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I have run into exactly the same issue on a Mi 11.
A working solution has been provided by Shendai on the GrapheneOS Discussion Forum (https://discuss.grapheneos.org/d/2753-trouble-installing-google-usb-drivers-w-fastboot-onto-windows-10/2).

For this, the usb/fastboot drivers for your phone need to be downloaded onto your computer.

To fix this, execute `set devmgr_show_nonpresent_devices=1` in an administrator command prompt, then unplug the phone from the computer.

Next go to the Device Management on Windows and uninstall all drivers related to the phone. Connect the phone to the computer again, find the now unknown device in the device manager and install the drivers by browsing the computer for drivers and selecting the corresponding files.

After this, you can run `adb reboot bootloader` to enter the bootloader and `fastboot devices` to verify, that the phone is being detected.

Worked in Windows 11 with disabled driver signature enforcement.